# What are wild cards?

Tags: legends-of-runeterra

When leveling up, I've opened several packs that contained wild cards of various rarities (rare, epic, etc), however I don't see them under my card collection. What are these cards, where can I find them in my collection, and what can they be used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Legends of Runeterra FAQ page](https://support-legendsofruneterra.riotgames.com/hc/en-us/articles/360036075453-Wildcard-FAQ)

> Wildcards can be traded for a card of corresponding rarity. That means that a Rare Wildcard can only be exchanged for, well, a Rare Card! We’ve listed the card rarities below:
>
> - Common
> - Rare
> - Epic
> - Champion

They can be used by right clicking the card you want to exchange a wild card for, and clicking the Wild Card button.

[image]